# NSArray to populate uiPickerView

Tags: swift3

I have the following NSArray:

```
rollupList =
[
    {"id":"1","rollup":"Acme Servicing","o_offered":"9780"},
    {"id":"2","rollup":"Acme Sales","o_offered":"4512"},
    ...
]
```

I'm trying to extract all "rollup" to display them in a uiPickerView without any success.

I'm able to get the "rollup" value when I enter the index

```
let rowLOALogs: NSDictionary = self.rollupList[0] as! NSDictionary
print((rowLOALogs["rollup"] as? String)!) //result: Acme Servicing
```

But I'm getting all kinds of errors when populating the uiPickerView:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return self.rollupList[row]
    //or return self.rollupList[row].rollup
    //or return return (self.kpiData[row] as AnyObject).rollup
}
```

I've been searching and testing different solutions provided by SO but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `String` from `titleForRow` method same way you are printing `rollup` from the array. So it should be like.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let rowLOALogs = self.rollupList[row] as! NSDictionary
    return rowLOALogs["rollup"] as? String
}
```

**Note:** In Swift instead of using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` you need to use Swift's native `Array` and `Dictionary` that will make things a lot easier to understand, even if you use Array of custom class objects or struct then it makes to easy to do what you want.